# PlayHT and Twilio streaming

Tags: twilio, streaming

we are trying to play a streaming audio on Twilio but we get just white noise. The audio is received from PlayHT as a mulaw format but not sure what we doing wrong.

Here is the Twilio function which connects to our server app:

```
exports.handler = function(context, event, callback) {
    let twiml = new Twilio.twiml.VoiceResponse();

    try {
        //const connect = twiml.connect();
        console.log("start");

        const connect = twiml.connect();
        connect.stream({
            name: "PlayHT",
            url: 'wss://f074-2a00-23a8-424f-b701-e862-5a32-4e45-397.ngrok-free.app'
        });
        
        console.log(twiml.toString());
        callback(null, twiml);
    } catch (error) {
        console.error("Error connecting to WebSocket:", error);
        callback(error);
    }
};
```

And here is the main websockets function in the server app:

```
wss.on('connection', function connection(ws) {
    ws.on('message', async function incoming(message) {
        // Parse the JSON string into an object
        const messageObj = JSON.parse(message);
        const event = messageObj.event;

        if (event == 'start') {        
            console.log('received: %s', message);

            const streamSid = messageObj.streamSid;

            // Create a test text stream
            const textStream = new Readable({
                read() {                    
                    this.push('This is a test');
                    this.push(null); // End of data
                },
            });

            // Stream audio from text
            const stream = await PlayHTAPI.stream(textStream, {
                voiceEngine: 'PlayHT2.0-turbo',
                voiceId: process.env.PLAYHT_VOICE_ID,
                output_format: "mulaw",
                quality: 'low',
                sample_rate: 8000
            });

            // Pipe the audio stream directly to the WebSocket
            stream.on('data', (chunk) => {
                console.log('sending: %s', chunk);
                
                // Encode chunk in base64
                const base64Chunk = chunk.toString('base64');

                // Prepare the JSON object in Twilio's expected format
                const twilioMessage = {
                    event: "media",
                    media: {
                        track: "outbound", // or "inbound" depending on your use case
                        payload: base64Chunk
                    },
                    streamSid: streamSid
                };

                // Send the JSON object as a string
                ws.send(JSON.stringify(twilioMessage));
            });

            stream.on('end', () => {
                const twilioMessage = {
                    event: "mark",
                    mark: {
                        "name": "PlayHT"
                    },
                    streamSid: streamSid
                };

                // Send the JSON object as a string
                ws.send(JSON.stringify(twilioMessage));

                console.log("--------------End stream--------------");
            });
        }
        else {
            if (event != 'media') {
                console.log('received: %s', message);
            }
        }     
    });
});
```

Logs seem ok, no errors on either side.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I am familiar with the Python SDK and not the JS, so take this with a grain of salt, but everything looks pretty good.

After encoding in b64, I also decode as utf-8.

I also don't specify "outbound" but I doubt that is giving your error.

You should make sure that twilio is actually connecting and you are able to stream the twilio signal in (check for "event" = "media" inbound streams).

Also, you can easily check that your play.ht code works by saving it locally and playing it back. I notice some differences in your Play.ht setup from mine but the two SDKs are fairly different.

Answer (score 0):

Update, seems like the PlayHT documentation was wrong. The parameters are outputFormat and sampleRate without the "_" in between...

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).